# Getting user's facebook fan page information such as likes count and followers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to FB development trying to build a solution to get the number of facebook likes on the user's fan-page using facebook authentication (by providing an option to authorize our facebook app which can get the authorized user's access token).
ex:https://graph.facebook.com/FANPAGE_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=name,fan_count

The problem is ,i have no idea how to get the access token of the fan-page, which provide access to the user's fan page (likes count) using any API methods .

However ,i have integrated successfully social sign-in using the following link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-social-login.

So please guide me a way to access the users(who authorized our fb app) facebook fan page likes count .

Thanks in advance

Comment: if any issues to understand the question please let me know

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Answer (score 1):

You Can see the likes by using the following code  [1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) is to create your AppID and App Seceret Use follwing Code to check likes

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/devronix.solutionspk/%2Fedforall&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=225116190942635" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```